# Volumns key detection for android device

Tags: java, android, key

Is there any way to detect the existence of the VOLUMN keys for android devices? Some features
should be hidden if there no VOLUMN keys. Appreciate for any help^.^

Answer (score 0):

For Volume Keys use KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN and KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP

```
@Override
 public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) 
     {
       // to your stuff here
       return true;
     }
 return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question how to find out if the key exists.

Comment: Sorry.. I couldn't found to test the existence of volume buttons but you can test other by using:

Configuration c = getResources().getConfiguration();
if(c.navigation == Configuration.NAVIGATION_DPAD)
      hasDpad = true;